# Modelio : JDK is not listed out in (Local) Libraries window. How to add JDK in Modelio 5.4.1?

Tags: modelio

I have java version "1.8.0_51" installed in Windows. When I do project configuration in Modeli0 5.4.1 , I noticed JDK local library is missing in the configuration window. Is it necessary to have JDK library for Java code -> Class diagram (Reverse) conversion?

1. I found library file extension is *.ramc. I tried to download JDK 1.8 (.ramc) file online. I couldn't find libraries for Modelio anywhere.
2. I tried to reach Modelio-Community. But Modelio's website is under maintenance. Only download page is working.
3. Without JDK also, I tried to reverse Java code to class diagram. I get following error.
   [Java code reverse Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30vYW.png)

Comment: I have found JDK for Modelio. https://github.com/ModelioOpenSource/ExtensionsForModelio/releases/download/5.3.1/JDK_8.191.02.ramc. It is mentioned in Model Github page "https://github.com/ModelioOpenSource/Modelio/issues/80". Downloaded & add manually.